# Alterar campos específicos string em Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tenho a seguinte string:

```
string = "Este aqui é o valor do cliente 000.000.00 01";
```

Preciso criar uma função, que "Procure" dentro dessa string que contém letras e números se existe um campo com esse formato `"000.000.000 00"`, caso existir, ele altere para o valor que eu vou setar em outra string, por exemplo, se ele encontrar, ele seta `"129.000.000 02"`.

P.S: Lembrando que ele precisa deixar os pontos e espaços desse mesmo jeito que esta ai, e só alterar após o `.` (pontos) e espaços, caso contrário meu relatório não lê.

Comment: Chegou a tentar algo com `RegEx`? Talvez seja melhor colocar o código da sua tentativa para ajudar a responder.

Comment: Será que você pode parar de fazer perguntas com exclamações! Já editei umas duas, e é muito estranho... :/

Comment: @brasofilo eu editei as outras :D

Comment: O @brasofilo tá tão inconformado que trocou a `?` da própria pergunta por uma exclamação também :) (pudera, é tanta `!` que contamina :P )

Comment: OK Amigo...@Dang, eu não tentei com REGEX, porque não sei como montar essa função para localizar um determinado campo dentro de uma string, porque os valores nunca serão os mesmos, entende ?

Comment: Eu editei várias também! @brasofilo

Comment: Tá vendo, 7605, suas exclamações tão *fritando* o pessoal, jjjjj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você só precisa de uma substituição simples com expressão regular; a verificação da existência ou não já fica por conta do método `replace`.

Um exemplo do `replace` no JavaScript:

```
var string = "Este aqui é o valor do cliente 000.000.00 01";
var str_subs = "129.000.000 02";
string = string.replace(/\d\d\d\.\d\d\d\.\d\d \d\d/g, str_subs);
```

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Perfeito @rui-pimentel, obrigado!

Comment: Por nada, que bom que deu certo!

Comment: @user7605 uma coisa que percebi agora... `\d` em expressão regular é uma forma equivalente a `[0-9]`, mas mais curta. Acho que fica mais elegante. Numa resposta que te dei noutra pergunta sobre expressão regular, você pode trocar os `[0-9]`por `\d`. Vou editar lá também.

Comment: Ah, blz @Renan, eu vi isso mesmo na internet, obrigado pela dica.

Comment: @Renan, será que preciso colocar algum caractere antes ? eu coloquei dessa forma: string = string.replace(/[0-9].[0-9].[0-9] [0-9]/g, str_subs); e não deu certo.

Comment: @user7605 essa expressão que você menciona pega números no formato "0.0.0 0". Você precisa adicionar mais `\d` ou `[0-9]` (recomendo `\d`) para dar certo. I.e.: `/\d\d\d[.]\d\d\d[.]\d\d\d[.]/g`

Comment: @RuiPimentel em expressões regulares o ponto faz match com qualquer caractere que não seja quebra de linha. Se quiser pegar pontos explicitamente, utilize `\.` ou `[.]`. De qualquer forma, +1.

Comment: Fala @Renan! Não entendi muito bem... já não estou fazendo isso? Usei a versão `\.`, é que é bem junto com o `\d`! :)

Comment: @RuiPimentel o problema está entre a minha cadeira e o meu teclado. Teu código ta correto, foi mal #LeituraDinâmicaDáNisso

Comment: Haha capaz, cara! Que alívio que não dei resposta furada!